# Vertical-Align Text&Image in RadPanelBarItem?

Tags: c#, css, telerik, panel

I am trying to vertically align the text and image of a RadPanelBarItem. Normally I would nest the two properties in a div, and apply a vertical-align: middle; to format these the way I want them, but unfortunately the Text and Image properties are nested within the RadPanelBar control.

[image]

Does anyone know the default classes of the RadPanelBarItem, and/or a simple way of aligning these two items that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a line height for the complete height of the element. This will vertically center your text.

Comment: This worked! By setting my line-height to 300%, I was able to vertically align my text the way I needed. Thanks!